# Chrome can't load specific pages - possibly due to Javascript

Tags: google-chrome, browser, java, javascript

So lately I've encountered a strange issue with Chrome where it seems to just not load pages with Javascript in them. Most notably this has been happening with my Facebook home page. Pages will perpetually try to load or become unresponsive entirely.

The reason I think it it's a Javascript issue is because disabling Javascript loads the pages, albeit without complete functionality provided by the Javascript components. It also seems to be an isolated issue as I can load said pages on my laptop just fine despite using the same version of Chrome and Google Account sync.

So yeah I'm not quite sure what to do to get these pages working again. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing chrome?

Comment: Yes. It fixed the problem for a day and then the same thing happened :(

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have some rogue extensions.

I would disable extensions, until your browser behaves normally.

I highly doubt it's Chrome's javascript engine. For example, I can access the Facebook home page without issue.

What URLs are causing you issues?

Comment: Unfortunately disabling extensions didn't do anything. As for other URLs, the biggest one I noticed was definitely Facebook's home page, but then I realised sites like - http://superhotgame.com/ - also would just keep loading perpetually and never complete loading.

I'll try to get more URLs as the issue progresses. I just find it incredibly strange that these sites were working just a couple days ago without issue.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Does it say "Resolving proxy script" at the bottom of the screen while the page loads?

Comment: Yup Windows. The status bar is strangely just blank/not there. Or in the case of Facebook, sometimes just perpetually 'waiting for <fb domain>'; if not becoming unresponsive entirely to the point where I might need to kill the process via Task Manager.